# How to achieve dynamic partial XML class serialization in .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, attributes, xml-serialization

I would love to use default .Net xml serializer to save my data into simple xml format. I have an `enum MemberCode { feild1 = 1, feild2 = 2 /*...*/}` at runtime I generate a  `List<MemberCode>` of members I want to save into xml (sometimes more sometimes less).

How to achieve such partial class serialization?

Comment: you mean `XmlIgnore`?, depending on the size of the class, serialization may not be the way to go, might be easier just to write a serializer yourself

Comment: probably, but note that my list is generated at runtime.

Comment: You can write a custom serializer method that takes a list as a parameter

Answer (score 0):

The code below may solve your problem.

We create a serializable class called MemberList, that contains an array of MemberCodes. After your list of member codes is populated during runtime, we convert it to an array and serialize it into XML. The results will be saved to a file called "test.xml" in your debug folder.

**XML Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <MemberList xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <Members>
        <Member>Field1</Member>
        <Member>Field2</Member>
        <Member>Field3</Member>
        <Member>Field2</Member>
        <Member>Field1</Member>
        <Member>field4</Member>
      </Members>
    </MemberList>
```

**Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Your member code list
            List<MemberCode> list = new List<MemberCode>();

            // Add some members to the list during runtime (replace with your logic)
            list.Add(MemberCode.Field1);
            list.Add(MemberCode.Field2);
            list.Add(MemberCode.Field3);
            list.Add(MemberCode.Field2);
            list.Add(MemberCode.Field1);
            list.Add(MemberCode.field4);

            // Create a new serializable member list
            MemberList memberList = new MemberList();
            // Convert your list to a serializable array
            memberList.MemberCode = list.ToArray();

            // Write the XML to a file
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MemberList));
            TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter("test.xml");
            serializer.Serialize(writer, memberList);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    [XmlRoot]
    public class MemberList
    {
        [XmlArray("Members")]
        [XmlArrayItem("Member", typeof(MemberCode))]
        public MemberCode[] MemberCode { get; set; }
    }

    public enum MemberCode
    {
        Field1 = 1,
        Field2 = 2,
        Field3 = 3,
        field4 = 4
    }
}
```